# How to print the selected checkbox values after submit

Tags: javascript, php, html

Here is the my checkbox list and the button which I need to submit the data..

```
<label>Access Locations </label>
     <br />


     <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" id="check1" class="pl" value="INT" /> dummy1
     <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" id="check2" class="pl" value="MV" /> dummy2
     <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" id="check3" class="pl" value="FV" /> dummy3
     <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" id="check4" class="pl" value="PS" /> dummy4

     <br />
     <h4 name ="checkboxvalues" style="color:green" id="result_checkbox"></h4>  
    
     <input type="hidden" name="employee_id_update" id="employee_id_update" />
     <input onclick="getCheckboxValue()" type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Update" class="btn btn-success" />
```

I am using below class when button clicked..

```
function getCheckboxValue() {

var l1 = document.getElementById("check1");
var l2 = document.getElementById("check2");
var l3 = document.getElementById("check3");
var l4 = document.getElementById("check4");

 
var res=" "; 
if (l1.checked == true){
  var pl1 = document.getElementById("check1").value;
  res = pl1 + ","; 
} 
else if (l2.checked == true ){
  var pl2 = document.getElementById("check2").value;
  res = res + pl2 + ","; 
}
else if (l3.checked == true){
document.write(res);
  var pl3 = document.getElementById("check3").value;
  res = res + pl3 + ","; 
}
else if (l4.checked == true){
  var pl4 = document.getElementById("check4").value;
  res = res + pl4 + ","; 
}

return document.getElementById("result_checkbox").innerHTML = "You have selected " + res ;

}
```

From above method I could see only one value in `checkboxvalues` as in the image when button clicked eventhough I have checked several checkboxes.

[image]

Can someone show me how to improve my code to show all the values when I checked several checkboxes?

If both check1 and check2 selected output should be

Output:

```
 You have selected INT,MV
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `if else if` statements so once one of the statements gets executed, the rest aren't getting executed. You can try an if statement for each checkbox, it will get the job done.

```
var res=" "; 
if (l1.checked == true){
  var pl1 = document.getElementById("check1").value;
  res = pl1 + ","; 
} 
if (l2.checked == true ){
  var pl2 = document.getElementById("check2").value;
  res = res + pl2 + ","; 
}
if (l3.checked == true){
document.write(res);
  var pl3 = document.getElementById("check3").value;
  res = res + pl3 + ","; 
}
if (l4.checked == true){
  var pl4 = document.getElementById("check4").value;
  res = res + pl4 + ","; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using an if-else ladder, which means if one of those conditions satisfies and gets executed, other blocks will be ignored. You can use multiple if blocks to avoid this situation.